# CoreNLP Lemma requirement for NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

NER annotator requires Lemma annotator to run (Line 576 in NERCombinerAnnotator).

I cannot find any usage of the LemmaAnnotation in NERCombinerAnnotator.
When I comment out this requirement, BasicPipelineExample works just fine.

Does NER actually use LemmaAnnotation?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I had thought it was used somewhere in SUTime, but there actually don't seem to be any uses. I think you're right that it could be deleted as a requirement.

Comment: I followed up by looking for uses of lemma() or hidden uses in the sutime rules themselves. Didn't see anything. I'll try eliminating it and seeing what difference it makes in a large result set, if any.

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, it's possible for the fine grained NER annotator to use it.  There may also be some hidden uses of lemma in some of the SUTime rules if there is a shorthand which looks at lemmas.  Since the benefit of leaving it out is minimal, no change.